# Class method returning a pointer to a member of class with Template

Tags: c++, class, pointers, templates

I am trying to write a function for a class "LinkedList" which has its own class "Node". The class "LinkedList" is a template class. I am trying to write a function "Foo_do_something" which returns a pointer to "Node". Following is the code:

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList{
public:
    class Node {
    public:
        T data;
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;

        Node(): next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}
        Node(const T & data): data(data), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}
    };
public:
    Node* Foo_do_something();
};

template <typename T>
Node* LinkedList<T>::Foo_do_something(){
    std::cout<<"Hello";
    Node *ptr = new Node(100);
    return ptr;
}
```

With this code I get the error:

```
error: ‘Node’ does not name a type
```

I understood that this is because "Node" belongs to class "LinkedList" scope. So I need to somehow add that information. I tried the following code but that also throws error.

```
LinkedList<T>::Node* LinkedList<T>::Foo_do_something(){
```

I can understand that if I define the function inside the class then the problem can be solved. But I was trying to keep the implementation of the function separate. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Try `typename LinkedList<T>::Node*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the correct form is:

```
typename LinkedList<T>::Node* LinkedList<T>::Foo_do_something() {
```

Recent compilers will also tell you that you need the `typename` if you try to compile it without that.

The reason `LinkedList<T>::` is necessary is because the return type is parsed before the compiler gets to the `LinkedList<T>::Foo_do_something` and knows for which class you are defining a member function and thus where to look for `Node`.

Why `typename` is necessary is explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords). Basically, it tells the compiler that `LinkedList<T>::Node` is a *type* and not something else, before the template is instantiated. The compiler needs to know that in order to parse the definition correctly, but before it actually knows what `T` is, it cannot be sure whether `::Node` refers to a type or a variable or a function, etc.

Alternatively you can use the trailing return type syntax, where lookup will already use the class context:

```
auto LinkedList<T>::Foo_do_something() -> Node* {
```